# Are there multiple branches of Glib?

Tags: glib

I'm trying to build Firefox from source and I'm getting hung up on some of the requirements.

I'm trying to build libIDL, which requires glib. I got glib built and installed to /usr/local, but when I try and configure libIDL, I get a failure at:

```
checking for LIBIDL... configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.4.0) were not met:

No package 'glib-2.0' found
```

I used the very latest version of glib that I can find, ftp://ftp.gtk.org/pub/glib/2.20/glib-2.20.3.tar.gz

However, I've also been searching around and am seeing references to libglib-2.0 such as at http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libglib2.0-dev

Are there 2 divergent branches of Glib, like a v1 and v2?

Comment: What platform are you trying to build on? Debian? Fedora? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install **glib-devel** in order to have the glib headers exist on your system.  Without the headers, autoconf will mark the library as missing.

Answer (score 2):

You installed glib from source which should have worked. The actual problem was most likely with the paths you chose to install into. The autoconf script may not be looking for glib where you installed it, or it may be looking into another directory first and finding an old version.